# How do I use C libraries in assembler?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I want to know how to write a text editor in assembler. But modern operating systems require C libraries, particularly for their windowing systems. I found this [page](http://pengu1n.is-programmer.com/posts/8304.html), which has helped me a lot.

But I wonder if there are details I should know. I know enough assembler to write programs that will use windows in Linux using GTK+, but I want to be able to understand what I have to send to a function for it to be a valid input, so that it will be easier to make use of all C libraries. For interfacing between C and x86 assembler, I know what can be learned from [this](http://pengu1n.is-programmer.com/posts/8304.html) page, and little else.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Comment: It's entirely possible to write a 'modern' program using an OS's gui services in assembler. It's just a lot of work. Any reason you're wanting to use assembler? Usually no one writes entire programs in that anymore, other than critical portions of a loop that need major hand optimization, or for educational experience.

Comment: MarcB: The reason I want to write it in assembler is because out of the languages that I've tried, I'm fondest of x86 assembler, by a large margin. And I anticipate using assembler in the near future, and that the better part of the purpose of my project is so that I can write assembler more easily.

Answer (score 10):

One of the most instructive ways to learn how to call C from assembler is to:

1. Write a C program that calls the C function of interest
2. Compile it, and look at the assembly listing (`gcc -S`)

This approach makes it easy to experiment by starting with something that is already known to work. You can change the C source and see how the generated code changes, and you can start with the generated code and modify it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The OS may define the calling standard (it pretty well *must* define the standard for invoking system calls), in which case you need only find where that is documents and read it closely.

Answer (score 1):

1. push parameter on the stack
2. call the function
3. clear the stack

The links you have in your question show all these steps.