# Calling C function in library from assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I need to call some functions from different C libraries in a nasm program.

Libraries:

```
 <sys/ptrace.h>
 <sys/wait.h>
```

...
and functions like ptrace, execl, wait, etc.

[How to use c library function fgets in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567055/how-to-use-c-library-function-fgets-in-assembly-language)

Comment: libraires :<sys/ptrace.h> / <sys/wait.h> / ...

Comment: functions : wait, ptrace, ...

Comment: You can edit the information into your question, no need to add it in comments.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. you had text in `<>`, but it wasn't marked as code. reformatted it for you.

Comment: I edited the question and removed the following text: "Also, someone had this idea to write the program in C and compile it with -S option to find out how it works. I did that too, but there was no result (I couldn't understand how it's working)." This is a *separate* question, and stack overflow would be happy to help you with it, but please ask it in a separate question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106530/how-should-we-handle-it-when-users-ask-about-two-separate-unrelated-issues-in-t

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use C libraries in assembler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589793/how-do-i-use-c-libraries-in-assembler)

Comment: If you can link with `gcc` then the `x86` wiki has some examples that could help [Hello World (Using C libraries and Linking with gcc)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/NASM_Syntax#Hello_World_.28Using_C_libraries_and_Linking_with_gcc.29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally two ways to use C/or any other HLL function from assembly program:

1. Static linking - if you are using linker, you can link your program together with the needed HLL generated .obj or .lib file and
2. Dynamic linking - your program links to the needed functions during the loading, not the compilation. There are two possible implementations:

   2.1. Manually load dynamic libraries and get the addresses of the needed functions. You have to use OS provided services for this. For example in Linux this is sys_uselib (pretty obsolete) or to load the library yourself and parse the ELF file for the function addresses;

   2.2. Build import table containing list of libraries and functions you want to use. Then the OS loader will automatically provide addresses of the functions in a placeholder variables from where you can call them indirectly.

All these methods are highly OS and assembler dependent, so I can provide example only for the assembler [I use](http://fresh.flatassembler.net):

[Import macros](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/fossil/repo/fresh/artifact/4d497cc280e) for FreshLib that build import tables for Linux.

[The same for Windows](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/fossil/repo/fresh/artifact/27d3602438bb10c16c3774d95a3ab189f2430779)

[Example of use for the library "libc.so" in Linux](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/fossil/repo/fresh/artifact/902828b979ad65730af0b46be1f5623b9ff41ef1)

[Example of use for the library "user32.dll" in Windows](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/fossil/repo/fresh/artifact/a44704e796b105624f67bbf48de2e89aa0e0c256)

Comment: The Linux `uselib` syscall is for the "old `a.out`" executable format - what Linux used before the adoption of ELF. Everybody should have stopped using it at least 15 years ago.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley - well, it is still available on some systems, but IMHO it is pain to be used. :)

Comment: "build import table" is seriously over-complicating the description of linking with `gcc -lfoo` to dynamically like with `libfoo.so`.  The linker will build PLT stubs for you.  Maybe it takes more work on Windows, but it's pretty simple on Linux.